# Who calm the Narasimha's anger after killing Hiranyakashyap?

Tags: scripture, vedas, vishnu

I heard many stories like lord **Narashimha** was uncontrolled with anger after killing **Hiranyakashyap**. So Lord **Shiva** and Mata **Laxmi** come to calm him. Want to know is any scripture tell about this incident ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharabha Murti from Sharabha Upanishad of Athaeva Veda and Taittiriya Aranyaka of Yajur Veda.

**Sharabha Upanishad.:**

> *स एकः श्रेष्ठश्च सर्वशास्ता स एव वरिष्ठश्च ।
> यो घोरं वेषमास्थाय शरभाख्यं महेश्वरः ।
> नृसिंहं लोकहन्तारं संजघान महाबलः ॥ ४॥*
>
> ***हरिं हरन्तं** पादाभ्यामनुयान्ति सुरेश्वराः ।
> मावधीः पुरुषं विष्णुं विक्रमस्व महानसि ॥ ५॥*
>
> *कृपया भगवान्विष्णुं विददार नखैः खरैः ।
> चर्माम्बरो महावीरो वीरभद्रो बभूव ह ॥ ६॥*
>
> *"That Maheshvara, full of supreme power had beheaded (killed) Narasimha who was destroying the world by holding a gigantic form of Sharabha"- 4*
>
> *" When Lord Rudra, the God of all had abducted Lord Vishnu by catching his foot, all gods prayed him that he should have mercy on Lord Vishnu and should not slaughter him. Lord Rudra had badly pierced the body of Lord Vishnu by stern blows of his acute nails. The most chivalrous Lord Rudra has been addressed as Virabhadra at that time when he put on leather apparel of Narsimha at that moment"- 5-6*

**YajurVeda's Taittiriya Aranyaka 10.49.1 says.:-**

> ***hariM harantam** anuyanti devAH | vishvasyeshAnaM vRiShabhaM matInAM ||*
>
> *"Salutations to Lord Hara who ends up his own form Hari, who's adored by all devas, who's the lord of universe."*

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Answer (score 8):

It's Prahlāda,son of Hiraṇyakaśipu.
[The Bhagavata Purana,Book 7,Chapter 9](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana/d/doc1128378.html)

> Nārada said:
> When, in spite of the Lord’s transcendence to attributes, the excellences of the Lord were highly extolled with deep reverence and
> devotion by his devotee Prahlāda, the Lord was pleased with him.
> Restraining his anger, he spoke to Prahlāda who was respectfully
> bowing to Him.